# C - server client multithreaded pthread_create failing

Tags: c, multithreading, client-server

im writing a multithreaded server, how ever i have tried to debug this but for some reason it doesn't actually go into the client thread called by pthread_create(), bottom of main. Any idea why pthread_create() is failing ?

Also i was wondering if it would be a good idea to send a struct to the client and the client send a struct back to the server as the main communication between the server and client? or should send() and recv() be a better way to implement?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fdServer;
    int accept_fd;
    int optVal = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in fromAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct pollfd* pServerPollFd;
    pthread_t threadId;
    socklen_t fromAddrSize;

    /*
     * Check user input and assign values
     */
    if(argc != 4)
        errorServer(WRONG_CLI);
    char* greeting = calloc(100,sizeof(char*));
    char* file_name = calloc(100,sizeof(char*));
    greeting = argv[2];
    file_name = argv[3];

    /*
     * Check pthread_key_create != 0 -> ERROR
     */
    if(pthread_key_create(&threadSpecificKey, dataDestructor))
        errorServer(SYSTEM_ERROR);
    int port_num = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(!((port_num <= 65535)&&(1<=port_num)))
        errorServer(INVALID_PORT);

    /*
     * Set up the server socket
     */
    fdServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(fdServer < 0)
        errorServer(SYSTEM_ERROR);
    if(setsockopt(fdServer, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optVal, sizeof(int)) < 0)
        errorServer(SYSTEM_ERROR);
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port_num);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if(bind(fdServer, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
        errorServer(PORT_ERROR);

    /*
     * Setup poll pool
     */
    pMessageBuffer = fifo_buffer_create(-1);
    poll_pool* pPool = poll_pool_create(MAX_CONNECTIONS + 1);
    pServerPollFd = poll_pool_allocate(pPool, fdServer);
    pServerPollFd->events |= POLLIN;
    int flags = fcntl(fdServer, F_GETFL);// Get the file access mode and the file status flags;
    if(fcntl(fdServer, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) == -1)// Set the file descriptor flags to the value specified by 3rd arg.
            errorServer(SYSTEM_ERROR);
    if(listen(fdServer, 4) != 0)//Allow only 4 connections to the server
            errorServer(SYSTEM_ERROR);




    while(1) {

            fromAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        /* Block, waiting for a connection request to come in and accept it.
         * fromAddr structure will get populated with the address of the client
         */
            while((accept_fd = accept(fdServer, (struct sockaddr*)&fromAddr,  &fromAddrSize)) != -1){
                printf("Someone connected \n");

            client_connection *pClientConnection = client_connection_create(accept_fd);
            client_details *pClientDetails = client_details_create();
            client_session *pClientSession = client_session_create(pClientConnection,pClientDetails);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&game_state_mutex);
            //SEARCH THE LINKEDLIST FOR THE GAME NAME - IF FALSE CREATE NEW LINKED ELEMENT
            C_lst requestedGame;
            clst_init(&requestedGame,NULL);
            clst_insert_next(&requestedGame,NULL,pClientSession);

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&game_state_mutex);
            write(accept_fd, greeting, strlen(greeting));



        /* Start a thread to deal with client communication - pass the
         * connected file descriptor as the last argument.
         */
            pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, client_thread, (void*)pClientSession);
            pthread_detach(threadId);
            }

    }
    free(greeting);
    free(file_name);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the beginning of the client_thread

```
void * client_thread(void* arg)
    {
    ssize_t numBytesRead;
    char buffer[MAXBUFFER];
    client_session* pClientSession = (client_session*)arg;

    if(pthread_setspecific(threadSpecificKey, pClientSession))
        errorServer(SYSTEM_ERROR);
/* below read fails because of the nonblocking fdServer from fnctl*/
 while((numBytesRead = read(fd,buffer,MAXBUFFER))>0){ 
    //loop code here
   }
```

Comment: non-blocking read will fail with EAGAIN if nothing is yet to read. You have to properly handle such situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you not checked for pthread_create return value and not print corresponding error message?

```
s = pthread_create(...);
if (s != 0) {
    errno = s;
    perror("pthread_create");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Source: pthread_create(3)

UPD. Also, for socket setting you can try getaddrinfo(3) instead of doing all by hand: http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html#getaddrinfo

UPD 2. What do you mean by 'sending struct'?

Comment: I've printed it out and it is a zero, so that means that it is executing it fine. This is really strange!

Comment: @MarkNicolle , so, now you know that problem is not with pthread_create. How about checking other system functions?

Comment: Yes i just see that i think the problem is with the fdServer it's set to nonblocking, however in my clent_thread(and it has been executing) is using read, therefore the while loop in the client_thread fails as it's not reading anything from read. and finishes the thread.
I'll update the client_thread but i think that i might need to use poll or select, is that right??

Comment: @MarkNicolle - why are you setting sockets to non-blocking in a one-thread-per-client server?

Comment: @MartinJames My original idea was to queue up the messages from multiple clients. Am i thinking the wrong way?